# Error while uploading the sketch for Arduino Mini

Tags: arduino-mini

I'm having a problem while uploading the program.

```
Arduino: 1.8.4 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Mini, ATmega328P"

Archiving built core (caching) in: C:\Users\UMME-K~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_566019\core\core_arduino_avr_mini_cpu_atmega328_3f323efdab4276426e9d8710d5d73f64.a
Sketch uses 3932 bytes (13%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
Global variables use 250 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1798 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
D:\Amna\arduino-1.8.4\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CD:\Amna\arduino-1.8.4\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\UMME-K~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_808790/buzzer.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "D:\Amna\arduino-1.8.4\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM4
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude done.  Thank you.

An error occurred while uploading the sketch

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

What should I do?

Comment: how is the Mini connected to USB? (or serial port?)

Comment: has it ever worked?

Comment: Google "avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync" and the Truth will be revelated.

Comment: @Juraj through USB cable , serial port

Comment: doing it for the first time @jsotola...

Comment: connects the cable to Reset pin?

Comment: https://www.google.com.pk/search?biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=guaHWq25IsG1gQbTuZnIDg&q=arduino+mini+program+upload&oq=arduino+mini+program+upload&gs_l=psy-ab.3...23636.28787.0.29006.15.15.0.0.0.0.330.1716.2-5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..9.6.1711...0j0i67k1j0i8i30k1j0i30k1.0.5aM_FwHjjdM#imgrc=p97hfh3t5iS8aM: @Juraj This is the arduino mini that im using and i have connected the data cable to it.. I am having issues while uploading the program. I think there is an issue with some driver or something if u know please let me know ....

Answer (score 2):

On Uno and other boards with USB on board, for flashing the [IDE resets the Atmega to bootloader](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoReset), sending signal over USB. Mini has not an build in USB and you connected it with an USB to TTL cable. Has this cable a Reset signal line? If yes, did you connect this line to Reset pin?

If not, then you need to do a manual reset in the right moment when avrdude sends the hex file. I count to 9 after the first attempt and then I push the reset button.

Comment: Well Thanks for your answer...Highly appreciated ... Anyhow the issue is solved  ...

Answer (score 0):

"If not, then you need to do a manual reset in the right moment when avrdude sends the hex file. I count to 9 after the first attempt and then I push the reset button."

In the IDE, if you select File:Preferences and turn on Verbose outputs, you can see when the IDE is about to download, there will appear "compiled xxx of 32xxx bytes), then3 attempts to download. If you press Reset when you see that message, or press & hold reset then release when you see that message, it is much easier to get the bootloader started at the right time (assuming one is actually loaded and there is nothing interfering with the signals on the D0/D1 pins).